# accordion effect not working with jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, accordion, effects

When I used accordion object with an older jquery it had worked.
  Now when I replaced it with Jquery 1.7.2, it is no more working. 
  I use effects.js of script.aculo.us to implement accordion. Is it 
  not compatible with Jquery 1.7.2?

I tried upgrading to the latest script.aculo.us (1.9.0) even then it did not work.
  Please help me if you have some solution?

Regards,
Harsha

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, and this is from failing at it before, is that you can't use two JQuery libraries at once. Meaning, you can't load jquery-1.7.2.js and then the prototype.js with it, you have to pick one or they both fail. So remove your call to any other JQuery libraries on that page except for prototype.js and script.acul.ous.